# Bad PDO Select statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My long polling isn't working:

*server.php*

```
<?php
require 'pdo.php';
set_time_limit(0);
while (true)
{

$requestedTimestamp = isset($_GET['timestamp']) ? (int)$_GET['timestamp'] : time();

  clearstatcache();

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare( "SELECT * FROM publication WHERE publication_time > :requestedTimestamp" );
  $stmt->bindParam( ':requestedTimestamp', $requestedTimestamp );
  $stmt->execute();
  $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (count($rows) > 0) {
$publication = $rows['publication'];
$timestamp = strtotime($rows['publication_time']);
$my = array('publication'=>$publication,'timestamp'=>$timestamp);
$myJSON = json_encode($my);
echo $myJSON;
break;


} else  {
    sleep(2);
    continue;
    }

}

?>
```

The problem is giving me a headache: Independent of `$timestamp`, the result I got from the SELECT is the same, in case I, my last `$timestamp = 1439056820 (08/08/2015 15:00:20);`

```
publication_time = timestamp field;
```

Comment: Have you tried a considerably different timestamp (in the range of months)?
and what is the difference in time between themost recent and the oldest publication?

Comment: Tried timestamp of 2018 and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks pretty fine to me. have you tried to bind the param as int?

```
$stmt->bindParam(':requestedTimestamp', $requestedTimestamp, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Maybe by passing the timestamp as a string you are getting some weird behaviour?

Edit: Since I had some more time, I actually tested the code, and magic:

> Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: '1440162495' for column 'timetest' at row 1

The issue is not with PDO, but the way that you pass data. The immediate solution is to convert your timestamp to a valid date, so something in the lines of:

```
$requestedTimestamp = isset($_GET['timestamp']) ? (int)$_GET['timestamp'] : time(); here
//convert unixtime to iso date
$requestedTimestamp = date('c', $requestedTimestamp);
clearstatcache();

$stmt = $pdo->prepare( "SELECT * FROM publication WHERE publication_time > :requestedTimestamp" );
$stmt->bindParam( ':requestedTimestamp', $requestedTimestamp );
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Hopefully, this will be enought :)

Comment: Failed :( , The Select continue showing results with any timestamp;

Comment: @MarleneOliveira Updated answer, it should perform as expected

Comment: Ok, i go try this when my house, sorry for bad english